# import .sql database into sqlite3 in macOS

Tags: ios, sql, database, ipad, sqlite

I tried creating sqlite3 database in my MAC OS X machine using the xxx.sql script file. But I am getting an error. The sql file is created on Windows system.

Command I used:

```
sqlite3 bizApp1.sqlite < DBCreationScript_8thNov2012_New.sql
```

Result:

```
Error: incomplete SQL: ??/
```

The error seems to be a syntax error.

Comment: Is there possibility that there is syntax error in your file, not in import command.

Comment: And where does that `??/` occur in the file?

Comment: The error i figured out in my Mac' Terminal (commandline) after i fired the "sqlite3 bizApp1.sqlite < DBCreationScript_8thNov2012_New.sql" statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're a beginner you can use an easy soft like [SQLite Data Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/)